# How to create a Qt GUI or QML/Qt quick project with command line qmake?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qmake

```
qmake -project .
```

this command creates a new `.pro` file as a new project with the same name as the parent folder and it automatically includes the available sources in the given folder too.

How to do the same for a Qt GUI project or a Qt quick one ?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. qmake generates Makefiles and projects. It is not a tool to create GUI. If you want to create GUI, then you need to write a code for that purpose (of course using Qt classes) or for shortcut you should use Qt Creator. If you want to go deeper without relying on Qt Creator then I suggest you the following book "C++ GUI Programming
with Qt 4" by Jasmin Blanchette and Mark Summerfield

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no template for a Qt GUI project from `qmake` command.
If tou want a template you can use Qt Creator.

Note that by default, it's a Qt GUI project, 
You can specify it in the `.pro` file

Qt project :

```
QT += gui
```

Non Gui project :

```
QT -= gui
```

Comment: and what about the 3 versions of the QML/Qt quick template ?